# How to retrieve an image from an URL? Errors

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, drawable

I am parsing a JSON Obj to get the url of an image. 
I am using this code.

```
private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String strPhotoUrl) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(strPhotoUrl).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        Log.e("TAGG", strPhotoUrl);
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAGG", e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I get an error that this must be done in an `AsyncTask`,i.e., Different Thread. But then how will I insert the drawable in an ImageView? Since `DoInBackground()` dosen't have access to UI elements. Also I don't have access to the URL until I parse the JSON obj I get the URL from. So what solution can I use in my situation. Thanks!

Comment: Use one of the [image-loading libraries for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), such as [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). They handle the background threading and such for you.

Comment: @CommonsWare is there no other option other than using external libraries. I'm new to using libraries. Could you please help me understand? Thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials on using Picasso in Android. In fact, last I checked, their git repo had a few examples in the README

Comment: @zgc7009 Thanks! I'll check it out

Comment: "is there no other option other than using external libraries" -- sure there are. However, image management is complex: background processing, scaling, caching, tracking as views get recycled in things like `ListView` and `RecyclerView`, and so on. Libraries have implementations of all of that, written by Android experts, that have been tested by those experts and thousands of other Android developers through the use of those libraries. If you think that you can do better than that for your use case, feel free to implement yet another set of image-loading code for your own use.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think you misunderstood me. My app just needs the image for display as a side function. It is not my main function at all. So I just wanted to avoid the hassle of using these libraries for a minute function in my app. I basically have to learn a whole lot of things for that. I didn't mean it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the UI elements from **[onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result))**.

So, you can make the API call and get the data in the background thread. After the image has been downloaded, you can set the image to the ImageView in the onPostExecute() method.

Comment: But I cannot use `InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(strPhotoUrl).getContent();` This in `onPostExecute`

Comment: No, you download the image in the background thread and use that image in post execute.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question I cannot do so in `doInBackground()` because I don't have the URL then. I have to parse the URL in `onPostExecute()`. Thats why. So do I have to use ANOTHER `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Well, yes. Image downloading cannot happen on the main UI thread. But, why can't you parse the URL in the background thread and get the image downloaded? Why do you need to do it in post execute? #justcurious

Comment: yes. I got. I was just doing that when you posted this comment. I am new to `AsyncTask`. I didn't know if I could parse JSON there. That's why. Sorry. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! No problem! Glad to be of help! :)

Comment: On an after-note, doInBackground() runs on the background thread. So, you can't make any UI operations from this thread, as you do not have access to the UI thread directly. So as long as your operations do not involve any UI elements, you can do anything in doInBackground().

Comment: I have an error. How do I return both the JSON response and the Drawable. Pls help

Comment: You have two options. Either you make the return type of the AsyncTask as an array of Objects. Or you can keep two global variables **inside** the AsyncTask. In doInBackground(), you can set the values to these variables and then later retrieve them in onPostExecute().